userstatsmanager works strangely
private fun isAppInForeground(packageName: String): Boolean {
        val usageStatsManager = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val beginTime = endTime - 10000
        Log.d("ForegroundCheck", "Querying events from $beginTime to $endTime")

        val usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime)
        if (usageEvents == null) {
            Log.d("ForegroundCheck", "UsageEvents is null")
            return false
        }

        var event: UsageEvents.Event
        var isForeground = false
        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            event = UsageEvents.Event()
            usageEvents.getNextEvent(event)
            Log.d("ForegroundCheck", "Event: ${event.packageName}, Type: ${event.eventType}, Time: ${event.timeStamp}")

            
            if (event.eventType == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED &&  event.packageName == packageName) {
                isForeground = true
            }
        }

        if (!isForeground) {
            Log.d("ForegroundCheck", "No matching event found for package: $packageName")
        }
        return isForeground
    }


if (usageEvents == null) {
Log.d("ForegroundCheck", "UsageEvents is null")
return false
}

Obviously, even though the code above confirms that usageEvents is not null, usageEvents.hasNextEvent() is output as false and the while statement is not executed.
How can I fix this?

Quoting the documentation for UsageStatsManager: "Usage data is aggregated into time intervals: days, weeks, months, and years." You are not necessarily going to be able to access data for the past 10 seconds.
